# Understanding Doctrine Query Builder?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

lets say i have department,college entities like follow

```
class Department{
     private $name;

     private $studentCount;


    /**  
    *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\CAPP\CollegeBundle\Entity\College", inversedBy="departments")
    *@ORM\JoinColumn(name="college_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
    **/
     private $college
}

class College
{

   private $name;

   private $departmentCount;

   /**
   *@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\CAPP\DepartmentBundle\Entity\Department", mappedBy="college", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
   */
   private $departments
}
```

when i write a doctrine query builder to fetch all department with following query

```
METHOD1:
return $this->getQb()->select("dp")
            ->from("DepartmentBundle:Department", "dp")
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
            ;
```

I got my result with all the fields,but when i am trying to access particular fields such `name` and `college`, with the following query

```
METHOD2:
return $this->getQb()->select("dp.name, dp.college")
            ->from("DepartmentBundle:Department", "dp")
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
            ;
```

i am getting error like

> col 10 near 'college FROM': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

what mistake i made here, doctrine fetches all departments with respective  college entities on `query method 1`, but when i try `query method 2` why it throws error.

Comment: in this case you can try Querying for Objects with DQL https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-with-dql

Answer (score 2):

Doctrine discourage using [partial object](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html) if it is not purelly for optimization.
You should use doctrine as intended: fully object oriented.

```
$this->getQb('dp')
    ->select("dp")
    ->from("DepartmentBundle:Department", "dp")
```

If you really want to use partial:

```
$this->getQb('dp')
    ->select("partial dp.{name,college}")
    ->from("DepartmentBundle:Department", "dp")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this please:

```
return $this->getQb('dp')->select('IDENTITY(dp.name)', 'IDENTITY(dp.college)')
            ->from("DepartmentBundle:Department", "dp")
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
            ;
```

If dp.name, or dp.college are composite keys then you need to add IDENTITY in order to make the query work and fix the issue

Comment: I am getting same error.  the query which i run is `$this->manager->createQueryBuilder("dp")
                ->select(["dp.name"," dp.college"])
                ->from("DepartmentBundle:Department", "dp")
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();`

Comment: try without the array please

Comment: I have update my answer please try now... I don't know if dp.name needs Identity into your schema @N.HariHaraSudhan

Comment: When i using `IDENTITY` it gives me an college_id only, not the `college`  object

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is any way the best answer but I'd just grab the collection and then use the get/set methods to pull the info...

```
$department = $this->getQb()->select("dp")
            ->from("DepartmentBundle:Department", "dp")
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

$name = $department->getName(); 
$college = $department->getCollege();
```